# How to split/parse a Java String to display cleanly with bullet points?

Tags: java, regex, formatting, string-formatting, thymeleaf

I have data being populated into a String with example data :

> Include: 1. lorem ipsum 2. blah blah
>   3. test test Exlude: 1. the quick  brown 2.fox 3. jumps over

Right now we are displaying the string as-is but would like to have it displayed to the user in a nicely formatted way such as:

> Include:
>
> 1. lorem ipsum
> 2. blah blah
> 3. test test
>
> Exclude:
>
> 1. the quick  brown
> 2. fox
> 3. jumps over

To make matters more complicated it seems like there was no real requirement for this String. Sometimes the data is separated by numbers (1, 2, 3), sometimes by bullet points (∙), and sometimes by hypens (-).

Not sure if there is a library built to help with this type of formatting already, right now ideas wise I'm thinking of making a new formattedToString() method that I could call to populate my popup div, possibly using some regex (i only know simple regex though). We are using ThymeLeaf as a templating engine if that helps too.

Thanks for any ideas/help!

Comment: None of this seems like a good idea to me.  Bullet points and enumerated lists ought to be CSS controlled things.  Server side should just be giving the page the List of Strings to display; formatting is CSS job.

Comment: The non-format you are describing sounds similar to Markdown (a flavor of which you used to write your question).  If it indeed is Markdown then you can likely apply a Markdown-to-HTML translator, and then parse the HTML (use a *bona fide* HTML parser).

Comment: If you really know *nothing* about the input format, however, then you simply cannot reasonably do what you describe, because that would constitute defining the format yourself.  In that case, you are best leaving it as a flat string (but preserving any user-provided formatting such as newlines and spaces, which takes a bit of care if you're displaying it in HTML).

Comment: "would like to have it displayed to the user in a nicely formatted way" - yes but what is the user looking at? a browser? a PDF? plain-text file?  I know ThymeLeaf can output HTML (but also XML) so what's the user going to use to consume the string you produce?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. For clarification right now all this data is just stored in one huge String. We want to populate a popup box on a webpage with this string but have each line show up under its own bullet point, like a list format. Right now my initial thoughts are to do regex to put the strings in a list and then use Thymeleaf to display bullet points while iterating over that list.

Answer (score 1):

For your example you can use a regex like this:

```
\b(?=\d+\.|Exclude:)
```

With a replacement string:

```
\n
```

The idea is to identify the patterns you want to use to add the `\n`. So, for above regex it will use `number[s] followed by a dot` or the word `exclude:`. If you want to add more patterns you have to do like this:

```
\b(?=Patt1|Patt2|...|PattN)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD0jE8/3)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- We are using ThymeLeaf
- Final output will be HTML
- Includes comes first; Excludes comes second (always)
- Nothing else is contained in the String

We could:

1. Replace `include` with `include<br/><ol>`

   `${#strings.replace(line, 'include', 'include&lt;br /&gt;&lt;ol&gt;')}`
2. Replace all numbers, or hyphens, or bullet points (in the incoming list) to `<li>`

   `${#strings.replace(line, '-', '&lt;li&gt;')}`
3. Replace `exclude` with `</ol>exclude<br/><ol>`

   `${#strings.replace(line, 'exclude', '&lt;/ol&gt;exclude&lt;br /&gt;&lt;ol&gt;')}`
4. Append `</ol>` to the incoming list string (i.e. the input)